# My form isn't sending visitors to the right page

Tags: javascript, forms

The page is here:

http://bluebeam.com/us/trials/punch/

It's supposed to send visitors to a download page after it's filled out but it's not. They still get an email confirmation after they fill it out but they aren't sent to a new page.

I don't know enough about javascript to trouble shoot this issue.

Anyone know why they aren't being redirected?

Thanks!

Comment: So you've literally done no troubleshooting? Sorry, you're in the wrong place. Stack is here to assist, not freelance development work for free.

Comment: Ouch... sorry. I've been pouring through it for a while now, I just don't have the solution yet so I thought I'd ask here to see if someone could quickly figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hrmn. I don't know if this is javascript related, but your form action says it goes to `index.asp?src=99`. You might want to put a different page that says download and have your code their to download and then redirect back to index.

And/or you might want to edit your question and add code fragments or other stuff to pinpoint where you might think the problem is.

Comment: Thanks! We figured it out. We needed to dynamically create the URL for the form in the Form Action and the form code.

Comment: Awesome! That's great guys. Keep it going. :)

Comment: @Andrew Richardson , may be you should accept the answer if it helped you?